# What is the unitary matrix for this two qubit circuit with $H$ and $I$?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

[image]

Above is a circuit I am provided. I am asked to write down the matrix representation of a $4 \times 4$ matrix representation of a unitary matrix for this circuit.

Using small endian notation (left to right):

The initial state is $|\psi\rangle = |x\rangle |y \rangle$

Then, $(H \otimes I) |x \otimes y \rangle = H|x\rangle \otimes I|y\rangle$ for the post - gate state.

The matrix representation for the unitary matrix $(H \otimes I) $ is

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

Am I correct?

Comment: Whether this is correct depends on the endian-ness convention you are using. Is H on the top qubit and I on the bottom qubit $H \otimes I$ or is it $I \otimes H$. You've correctly computed $I \otimes H$. I think that's the less common convention, but it is used e.g. in Quirk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are incorrect. The tensor product is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) as

[image: kronecker product]

With this in mind, the answer is

$$
H \otimes I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\times I & 1 \times I \\
1 \times I & -1 \times I
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &  0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 &  -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$